# Finding the real potential and streamfunction from a complex potential

Tags: complex-analysis, fluid-dynamics

I'm trying to solve the following problem given on a previous exam in my fluid mechanics course:

A stationary flow is given as the following complex velocity potential:

$$
\beta(z) = \ln(z - a) + \ln(z + a) + Uiz
$$

Find the real velocity potential and the stream function.

Let's first of all rewrite this as:

$$
\beta(z) = \ln(z^2 - a^2) + Uiz
$$

We know that the real velocity potential and the stream function are respectively given as the real and imaginary parts of the complex potential:

$$
\beta = \phi + i\psi
$$

We know that a complex logarithm can be rewritten as:

$$
\ln(z) = \ln(r) + i\theta = \frac{1}{2}\ln(x^2 + y^2) + i\arctan2(y,x)
$$

With this we can rewrite the complex potential as

$$
\beta (z) = \frac{1}{2}\ln(x^2 - y^2 - a^2 + 4x^2y^2) + i\arctan2(2xy,x^2 - y^2 - a^2) + U(-y +ix)
$$

which gives:

$$
\phi = \frac{1}{2}\ln(x^2 - y^2 - a^2 + 4x^2y^2) - Uy, \quad \psi = \arctan2(2xy,x^2 - y^2 - a^2) + Ux
$$

Is this correct? I'm having some doubts since I wouldn't expect the somewhat esoteric arctan2 in an answer to an exam problem.

Comment: This looks reasonable. I don't know what your instructor has told you about the complex logarithm, but it's not exactly convention to write out its expression using $\arctan 2$. This is because the complex logarithm has different branches. Thus we usually write $\log(z) = \ln(|z|) + i \arg(z)$, where $\arg$ is some branch of the argument function.

Comment: Ok, good =) I've only been taught $\ln(z) = \ln(r) + i\theta$. Is $\arctan2$ only used when the complex number is known in terms of its real and imaginary part? In that case I failed to mention that the problem explicitly states that $z = x + iy$.

Comment: The use of $\arctan 2$ would correspond to what we usually call the principal branch of the logarithm, i.e. the one where the argument lies in $(-\pi, \pi]$.